# Different APK contents when using "Rebuild Project" vs "Run"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently working on an app that uses the Affectiva SDK with

```
implementation "com.affectiva.android:affdexsdk:3.2"
```

it contains a platform specific file `lib/armeabi-v7a/libaffdexface_jni.so`.

When I build the app using "Rebuild Project" in Android Studio or `gradlew assembleDebug` in a console I get a ~10MB APK that includes this file and runs fine on my device. But when I simply use the "Run" button in Android Studio I get a ~6MB APK without the file. The app then crashes with

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.test.facial.recognition.debug-rkAp4fGhSFRMATj614orZw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.facial.recognition.debug-rkAp4fGhSFRMATj614orZw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libaffdexface_jni.so"
```

My guess is that "Run" builds a device specific APK for speed reasons. I'm using a Pixel 2 which is ARMv8 and not ARMv7a, therefore the file is probably skipped. ARMv8 is backwards compatible with ARMv7a, so this is no issue. (since it runs fine when using "Rebuild project" or console and installing it manually)

Is there a way to solve this? Can I make "Run" use universal APKs instead of device specific? Or can I tell it to include ARMv7a binaries in ARMv8 builds?

Comment: Sounds strange. What happens if you press menu `Run > Debug app`?

Comment: Same result as `Run > Run`: file not included and crash

Comment: So, that's good, kind of. What build variant is selected in AndroidStudio? `debug`?

Comment: Yes, it's `debug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I include

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```

in `build.gradle` it works. The [documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html) says

> Specifies the Application Binary Interfaces (ABI) that Gradle should
>   build outputs for and package with your APK.

but I don't even use the NDK, so I don't know why this works. If anyone knows why please comment. Also, cleaner solutions than this one are highly welcome.